# Install repository and sync project doesn't work

Tags: android, macos, android-studio, repository, build.gradle

I get this message when I wanna run the android app on android studio.

> Error:(28, 13) Failed to resolve: com.android.support:design:26.0.0

if I click the install repository and sync project nothing happens.

And this is my idea.log file after I click install repository and sync project

> 2017-06-13 13:05:08,498 [1840757]
>   INFO - ea.sdk.wizard.SdkQuickfixUtils - Downloading *://dl.google.com/android/repository/repository2-1.xml 
>   2017-06-13 13:05:09,088 [1841347]
>   INFO - ea.sdk.wizard.SdkQuickfixUtils - Downloading *://dl.google.com/android/repository/sys-img/android/sys-img2-1.xml 
>   2017-06-13 13:05:09,251 [1841510]
>   INFO - ea.sdk.wizard.SdkQuickfixUtils - Downloading *://dl.google.com/android/repository/sys-img/android-wear/sys-img2-1.xml 
>   2017-06-13 13:05:09,416 [1841675]
>   INFO - ea.sdk.wizard.SdkQuickfixUtils - Downloading *://dl.google.com/android/repository/sys-img/android-tv/sys-img2-1.xml 
>   2017-06-13 13:05:09,561 [1841820]
>   INFO - ea.sdk.wizard.SdkQuickfixUtils - Downloading *://dl.google.com/android/repository/sys-img/google_apis/sys-img2-1.xml 
>   2017-06-13 13:05:09,717 [1841976]
>   INFO - ea.sdk.wizard.SdkQuickfixUtils - Downloading *://dl.google.com/android/repository/sys-img/google_apis_playstore/sys-img2-1.xml 
>   2017-06-13 13:05:09,852 [1842111]
>   INFO - ea.sdk.wizard.SdkQuickfixUtils - Downloading *://dl.google.com/android/repository/addon2-1.xml 
>   2017-06-13 13:05:10,027 [1842286]
>   INFO - ea.sdk.wizard.SdkQuickfixUtils - Downloading *://dl.google.com/android/repository/glass/addon2-1.xml 
>   2017-06-13 13:05:10,152 [1842411]
>   INFO - ea.sdk.wizard.SdkQuickfixUtils - Downloading *://dl.google.com/android/repository/extras/intel/addon2-1.xml

After these lines nothing happens again.

I had to change https as "*"

and this is my build.gradle file:

```
android {
compileSdkVersion 26
buildToolsVersion '26.0.0'
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.xxx.yyy"
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 26
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}

dependencies {
compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-            
core:2.2.2', {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-    
annotations'
})
compile 'com.android.support:design:26.0.0'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.+'
compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'

testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

Comment: can u share your gradle file here?

Comment: i added the gradle file to question

Comment: u getting any error in java file?

Comment: there is no error

Answer (score 0):

add this in dependencies in your gradle file module.app

```
    compile 'com.android.support:design:25.2.0'
```

Comment: problem is not about version.install does nothing in other versions too.